# Is an angular service provided to a component destroyed when the component is destroyed?

Tags: angular

I have a service with an interval that checks the state of the data every 10 seconds to update a label in a component. This is only required when on the page where the component exists. The component looks a little like this:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'editor-status',
  templateUrl: './editorStatus.component.html',
  providers: [EditorStatusService]
})
export class EditorStatusComponent implements OnDestroy {
  constructor(private service: EditorStatusService){};
  public ngOnDestroy(): void {
    service.destroy();
  }
}
```

My service has this kind of structure:

```
@Injector()
export class EditorStatusService {
  private intervalId: any;
  constructor() {
    this.intervalId = setInterval(() => { 
      /* code to update ui */ 
    }, 10000);
  }
  public destroy(): void {
    clearInterval(this.intervalId);
  }
}
```

Are services provided to components in this way built each and every time the component is instantiated? If I don't destroy the listeners will I create a memory leak each time this page is loaded and then navigated away from?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A service provided by a component is automatically destroyed when the component is destroyed.

You can test this via the ngOnDestroy life cycle hook in your service:

```
ngOnDestroy(): void {
  console.log('service destroyed');
}
```

It should write 'destroyed' in console when the component is destroyed.

Comment: Would this include any subscriptions in the service being unsuscÏbribed too or is there a potential leakage here?